# TensorFlow: use same model twice generate double variables

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to use a pretrained model which is trained by myself, and it looks like:

```py
    def Conv2D(x, channel, kernel_size, stride=1, bias=True, padding='same',name="conv2d",reuse=False):
        with tf.variable_scope(name):
            conv_out = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(channel,kernel_size=kernel_size,strides=(stride,stride),padding=padding,use_bias=bias)(x)
            return conv_out

    class MyNet_Pretrain():
    def __init__(self):
      self.network_name = "net_pretrain"

    def _mynet_pretrain(self,l1):
      with tf.variable_scope(self.network_name) as vs:
        conv1_down = ReLU(Conv2D(l1, 32, 3, 1, True,name='conv1_down'))
        conv2_down = ReLU(Conv2D(conv1_down, 64, 3, 2, True,name='conv2_down'))
        conv3_down = ReLU(Conv2D(conv2_down, 128, 3, 2, True,name='conv3_down'))

        conv3_down_upsample = tf.image.resize_bicubic(conv3_down, [128, 128], True)
        conv1_up = ReLU(Conv2D(conv3_down_upsample, 64, 3, 1, True,name='conv1_up'))
        conv1_up_upsample = tf.image.resize_bicubic(conv1_up, [256, 256], True)
        conv2_up = ReLU(Conv2D(conv1_up_upsample, 64, 3, 1, True,name='conv2_up'))
        conv3_up = Conv2D(conv2_up, 4, 1, 1, True,name='conv3_up')

      return conv3_down, conv3_up
```

and I want to use it to calculate the feature maps of generated image and target image, like this:

```py
    net_pretrain = MyNet_Pretrain()
    outputs_pretrain1 = net_pretrain._mynet_pretrain(outputs)
    outputs_pretrain2 = net_pretrain._mynet_pretrain(target_pl)
```

However, when I check all trainable variables, I found the variables of this network doubled:

```
    [<tf.Variable 'net_pretrain/conv1_down/conv2d_9/kernel:0' shape=(3, 3, 4, 32) dtype=float32>, ...<tf.Variable 'net_pretrain_1/conv1_down/conv2d_15/kernel:0' shape=(3, 3, 4, 32) dtype=float32>, ...]
```

I am not sure where the problem is. Thank you so much!

Comment: You seem to be using TensorFlow 1.x, but you have tagged with `tensorflow2.0`, what version are you actually using?

Comment: sorry, I am using tensorflow 1.15.0, and I have corrected the tags.

Comment: Are you using a notebook?

Comment: Yes, I'm using google colab